# What is the difference between .container .flexbox and .flex-container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

i'm trying to understand and use flex boxes. as I search the web for examples, i've ran into flexbox, flex-container, and container. 
In all of the examples, they have a property of  {display:flex;}
does it not matter what class we call it, as long as we have display:flex as the property?

Comment: Read this https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure! It does not matter what class you call it. You can name a class `square`. But style it to be a circle like that   `.square{   border-radius: 50%;}`. All of the magic is in the css propertive not the class name. Class is just a name.

Comment: thank you @Duannx you're the only one with a helpful answer

Comment: @TEvon, You are welcome. If you think my answer is helpful, please accept it. :D

Comment: I think you miss some basic understanding. My advice is you should start learning the basic and do not use any library before you know what is it. Please complete [this tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp). After that, you will get the concept.